# Is there a limit to plotting markers with folium?

Tags: python, pandas, plot, data-science, folium

I'm plotting the missions ran by the USAF on North Korea during the Korean War.

The following is the map with 2800 plots.

[image]

I have a total of about 7500 plots, but whenever I try to plot above 2800 a blank map renders. I'm rendering on a pc laptop. Would it render if I use a desktop? Or is this a limit with folium?

I'm not speculating that it's an issue with the data. I'll share the coordinates data in case someone would like to explore it: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16OLqtxBz6PIJmq57fX0375zNbkatPg1CQDVBXKAlAew/edit#gid=1204279229) to public excel sheet.

Comment: Are you doing popups by chance?

Comment: @BobHaffner nope I’m not using popups

Comment: hmmm... rendering in a jupyter notebook?

Comment: You should be able to plot over 2800.  I've had cases where it wouldn't render in a jupyter notebook so I had to save it then open it in a browser.  Also, although those 7500 should plot, it will probably take a while.  Check out FastMarkerClusters for a significant speed up

Comment: @BobHaffner yea I used jupyter notebook. That’s a good suggestion. I’ll try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Bob Haffner suggested you can use FastMarkerCluster from Folium library.
Here is my code, in my file there is ~500K points.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from folium.plugins import FastMarkerCluster

rome_lat, rome_lng = 41.9028, 12.4964
with open("file_name.json", 'r') as f:
  # create a new DataFrame
  samples = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(f.read()))        
# init the folium map object
my_map = folium.Map(location=[rome_lat, rome_lng], zoom_start=5)
# add all the point from the file to the map object using FastMarkerCluster
my_map.add_child(FastMarkerCluster(samples[['latitude', 'longitude']].values.tolist()))
# save the map 
my_map.save("save_file.html")
```

This code takes ~10ms to render the map.

For more details example please follow this link:
[FastMarkerCluster example](https://github.com/bobhaffner/medium_posts/blob/a059ef00be902db8da40cd356cce74d3aa00f5ca/folium_markerclusters/folium_markerclusters.ipynb)

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: It's Marker not Circle.

Comment: The link to "FastMarkerCluster example" is broken.  Is there another version or archive of that blog post?

Comment: Hi @blong you can try explore the code from the old post in Bob Haffner's GitHub [LINK](https://github.com/bobhaffner/medium_posts/blob/master/folium_markerclusters/folium_markerclusters.ipynb)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is that we can add a specific number of markers(let's say 3000 markers) on a layer, using `folium.map.FeatureGroup()` function that will add 3000 markers on a single layer, and we can add that layer to the map using `add_child()` function, which reduces the number of layers on the map. I got the result for 20,000 Markers and 3000 line string. And is able to load within 40-45 seconds.